# Programmatically Draw View in iPhone: What to do for iPad Version

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have drawn a `UIView` (i.e. `UIButton`) in my code for an iPhone app.

Now I want to develop a iPad version, but since the screen size of the iPhone and iPad differ, the `UIView` should have different sizes. What can I do to deal with the views programmatically?

Comment: Show some code how you draw the button. Usually if drawing is implemented correctly you don't have to do anything. Initialize the button, set the frame and the UIView's drawInRect: method will be called with the bounds and everything should draw as expected.

Comment: @graver UIButton *name = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(105,180,250,25)]; As you see, (105,180,250,25) is hardcode

Comment: This is not drawing a button, this is just initializing a ready one. I though you have subclassed UIButton or UIView and perform manual draw implementing drawInRect: method. The answers below show you what to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for a universal iOS app, ask what device you are serving and have your view drawn accordingly

so in your view controllers use::

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {

         //draw accordingly to your layout for iPad

    }
   else { //iphone layout
   }

}
```